# What namespace for IActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I know it's outdated, but we have an existing Web Api Project using .Net Framework 4.7.2.
We are not in a position to upgrade the whole project, but I need to introduce a new method in the form:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> myMethod(string requestUrl)
{
   ......
   Return Content(result, "application/json");
}
```

I dont have a reference to the library that supports IActionResult, can someone tell me what the reference should be for 4.7.2

Comment: That `IActionResult` is .net core and found in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`. You can't reference this from .net framework. You need to use `IHttpActionResult`.

Comment: You can reference `ActionResult`